# UIImage from system symbol name in c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, uikit, maui

In a MAUI app, I'm attempting to initialize a UIImage from a system symbol name (one of the icons in SF Symbols). According to [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/3622472-init) you can do so with `UIImage.init?(systemSymbolName name: String)`, however I can't seem to find the corresponding binding in the Xamarin UIKit API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiimage?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

I've tried just using `item.UIImage = new UIImage("gearshape");`, but obviously it doesn't work, as it's expecting a filename. Am I missing something here, or is this just impossible in .net?